# How to calculate the distance between 2 coordinates on a plane which only allows horizonal and vertical movements

Tags: measure-theory

Whilst the Pythagoras theorem is useful when calculating the distance between 2 coordinates diagonally, how is the distance calculated when the plane only allows horizontal and vertical movements (not diagonal)?

Comment: Look up taxi-cab geometry.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks! Looks like the formula is the sum of the differences between the 2 points on the x and y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Taxicab Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), the distance is the sum of vertical and horizontal distance between the 2 points.